# How should I loop over the batch items in a tensorflow tf.keras.layers.Layer?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I have a computation requiring to sum a high number of 2D maps. Unfortunately, this cannot hold on a GPU memory so I have to break down the computation.

```py
class Decode(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, scale_factor, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.scale_factor = scale_factor
    def build(self, input_shape):
        _, self.height, self.width, _ = input_shape
        # high resolution map of positons
        self.positions = tf.stack(tf.meshgrid(
                                tf.range(0,self.width*self.scale_factor, dtype=tf.float32),
                                tf.range(0,self.height*self.scale_factor, dtype=tf.float32)), axis=-1)
    def call(self, mean, variance, confidence):
        # Doesn't fit in memory
        return tf.reduce_sum(
            tf.exp(
                -tf.reduce_sum(
                    (self.positions[tf.newaxis,:,:,tf.newaxis,:] - tf.reshape(mean, [-1, 1, 1, self.width*self.height, 2]))**2, axis=-1
                )/(2*tf.reshape(variance, [-1, 1, 1, self.width*self.height]))
            )*tf.reshape(confidence, [-1, 1, 1, self.width*self.height]),
            axis=-1
        )/16
```

I would like to loop over all the items in the batch with something like

```py
    def call(self, mean, variance, confidence):
        batch_size = confidence.get_shape().as_list()[0]
        acc = tf.zeros((batch_size, self.height*self.scale_factor, self.width*self.scale_factor))
        for b in range(batch_size):
            acc[b] = tf.reduce_sum(
                tf.exp(
                    -tf.reduce_sum(
                        (self.positions[:,:,tf.newaxis,:] - tf.reshape(mean[b], [1, 1, self.width*self.height, 2]))**2,
                        axis=-1
                    )/(2*tf.reshape(variance[b], [1, 1, self.width*self.height]))
                )*tf.reshape(confidence[b], [1, 1, self.width*self.height]),
                axis=-1
            )/16
        return acc
```

However, this loop cannot be defined since the batch size is not known (`None`).

Is there a way to loop in the batch dimension in an eager way?
Is there another implementation that you think would work better?

Comment: Does `batch_size = len(confidence)` work?

Comment: It seams so, yes :o ?!? (but I have another error about acc[b] not supporting item assigment)